# Como configuro um banco de dados MySQL que está na minha máquina para ser acessado no moodle hospedado na web?

Tags: mysql, moodle

Contratei os serviços de hospedagem do Uol Host, porém eu não posso alterar o banco de dados fornecido por eles. Gostaria de saber como faço para conectar um banco de dados da minha máquina oo moodle que está instalado no host. Na instalação do moodle aparece isso.
[image: Na instalação do moodle]

MySQL Workbench recém instalado.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Como assim, você contratou o bd e não pode mexer nele?

Comment: ele deve estar usando um banco  de plataforma tipo  wordpress etc, esse provedor não permite alterar a extrutura de banco com plataformas instaladas pelo proprio painel, mas  se  n  me engano ele tem  direito a 5 bancos Mysql e  1 Postgr

Comment: Isso. Eu não consigo alterar o formato de arquivos pois requer super privilégios e eu não tenho. Tenho que usar um banco de dados diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro vc irá precisar de um IP statico ou um Dynamic DNS para acessar seu site, e também  precisará que as portas do seu IP estejam  liberadas no  seu provedor de internet, sem isso não  tem como você fazer a conexão remota com o  seu  host

1. Você pode fazer a verificação de qual o [seu ip  aqui](http://www.meuip.com.br/)

   Pode verificar se as portas estão abertas em  [seu servidor aqui](http://canyouseeme.org/)

   Precisará liberar as portas no  seu  roteador/model  veja como  em
   algum [totorial aqui](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=liberar%20porta%20de%20modem&oq=liberar%20porta%20de%20model&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.16703j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Caso esteja tudo ok

2. No  seu Host Banco  de dados você digitará seu ip exemplo
   200.133.56.23 ( o que aparecer para você no  site do meuip.com.br)

   Banco de dados  Insira o nome do  seu  banco

   usuario e senhas (por padrão é usuario > root e a senha branca) caso
   tenha outro usuário e senha os digite

   Prefixo da tabela é opicional

   Porta do banco de dados geralmente é 3306 mas caso tenha alterado
   especifique a que utiliza

   Unix Socket deixe em branco

Comment: > Primeiro vc irá precisar de um IP statico ou um Dynamic DNS para acessar seu site. Então, o site já tá no ar, eu consigo iniciar a instalação, porém não consigo conectar meu banco de dados na aplicação como pede na imagem(provavelmente por causa da porta que você mencionou). E com "provedor de internet" você fala do modem ou realmente do provedor que eu contratei?

Comment: E a porta que eu tenho que liberar é a mesma do banco de dados, certo? Eu tentei liberar a porta 80 no modem e testei no site "canyouseeme" mas até agora sem sucesso. No meu modem tem essas opções ![modem](https://imgur.com/d8V4p41).

Comment: Sim, a mesma do  banco  que npo  geral é a 3306, qual provedor vc usa ? geralmente oi, net, gvt  costumam bloquear as portas, vc tem  que fazer um trigger também  no  sue  rotador da porta local para a porta externa é bem  complexo

Comment: Entendi. O provedor que eu uso é a Cabo Telecom. Sobre o trigger, teria como mandar um tutorial?